# How can I derive a Django queryset to a REST request based on API parameter?

Tags: python, django, rest

I am building a Django application that exposes a REST API by which users can query my application's models. I'm following the instructions [**here**][1].

I want to make it such that when the API endpoint /api/myObject/60/ is hit, it should return lookup myObject with ID==60 and then return the value of getCustomMyObjectsList() which is a method of myObject. But I've been going around in circles for 2-3 days trying to figure how to do it.

My Route looks like this in myApp's url.py:

```
from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.DefaultRouter()    router.register(r'myObjects/(?P<id>\d+)/?$', views.MyObjectsViewSet)
url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
```

My Serializer looks like this:

```
class MyObjectSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyObject
    fields = ('id', 'name',)
```

My Viewset looks like this:

```
class MyObjectsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyObjects.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['id']).getCustomMyObjectsList()
    serializer_class = MyObjectSerializer
```

When I hit /api/myObjects/60/ I get the following error from the first line of the Viewset:

```
name 'self' is not defined
```

Why?? How do I grab the ID of 60 in my viewset and get fetch the MyObject with that ID?
Can someone please show me the exact code I need to write in MyObjectViewSet()?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`self` is a reference to the object instance and not available when defining class variables. You should override the `get_queryset` method to achieve your goal, where the request object is available by accessing `self.request`.

For more details you can check out http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering